# Error C4430 missing type specifier - int assumed. C++ does not support default-int

Tags: c++

I'm getting an missing type specifier error for line 12 ( `inline CUserCmd*cmd = nullptr;`) for this code and all the answers i can find are about functions but this is an inline variable so I'm rather confused.

```
#pragma once
#include "../core/interfaces.h"

class CEntity;
namespace globals
{
    inline CEntity* localPlayer = nullptr;

    // update the local player pointer
    void UpdateLocalPlayer() noexcept;

    inline CUserCmd*cmd = nullptr;
    inline bool sendPacket;
}
```

Additionally I'm getting this syntax error "Error C2143 syntax error: missing ; before *" (also for line 12) which i don't understand as when i add it (CUserCmd **;** *cmd) i get another error I'm guessing this is caused by the first error but i don't really know.

As stated earlier I tried looking through various stack overflow questions and wikis but all the stuff i can find is about functions which isn't exactly helpful.

Comment: What is `CUserCmd`?

Comment: Which compiler are you using? I declared an empty-class `CUserCmd` in the namespace and it works fine with the `std=c++17` flag in g++.

Comment: @mch its a class

Comment: Program [works here](https://godbolt.org/z/d8sa1PP8o)

Comment: `CUserCmd` is not declared

Comment: @LightningSheep The point is have you included a definition or declaration for it? The compiler is telling you that you haven't, and there's no such thing in the code you have posted.

Comment: Certainly `CUserCmd` is not declared in `../core/interfaces.h`.  When I uncomment `class CUserCmd;` in your code, it compiles fine with a C++17 compiler.

Comment: You write _"i get another error I'm guessing this is caused by the first error but i don't really know."_. Which error is this? Show the **verbatim** error message.

Comment: @LightningSheep Strange thing is that you've added a declaration for `CEntity`, why didn't you do the same thing for `CUserCmd`? Do you think that it's declared in `../core/interfaces.h`? You should double check that assumption.

Comment: If you look in the compiler output rather than the error list it'll likely give you more detail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't provided a complete program, but I suspect that's part of the problem.

The two errors you mention both point to the compiler being unable to find a definition for `CUserCmd`.

If that's included in a header, make sure you `#include` it.